# How can I make a full backup of a hosted Linux server?

Tags: backup

I want to rent a server at Vultr for some server-side programming using Mono. I'm quite new to Linux.

Despite knowing that Hosting companies care about server security I want to make sure to be able to reset my full installation when needed or to transfer it to another hosting provider if necessary.

Is this easily possible? Can I replace an existing installation on a running server?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

#### Development Machine & Deployment Server

Backing up or transferring a full machine is impractical, to say the least.

The normal approach is to use the hosted server to deploy your application and develop the application on your development machine.

On your development machine you develop and test your application. If you are happy with it or if you want to test new features or bug fixes, you package it and install it on the deployment platform. In your case the deployment platform would be the hosted server.

This removes the need to back up the hosted server. If you want to move to a different hosting company or 'reset' the existing server to a blank new server, you can just install your application on the new server and you are good to go.

The only things you have to backup from your deployment server are any databases or other data that you've collected on your deployment machine.

Make sure to backup your development machine and, preferably, use a version system (Git, Mercurial, etc.) to keep track of your source files.

It pays and saves a lot of time to automate the package and install steps.

#### Reinstall Using Package List

Most Linux flavours have a package manager for installing and managing packages. You can compile a list of the installed packages and use that to populate a new machine or re-install on your existing machine after you've 'reset' it.

See this [post](https://askubuntu.com/q/17823/425630) for the Ubuntu way of doing this.

#### Select Your Hosting Provider

Some hosting providers allow you to make backups or take snapshots of your machine that you can use to restore the machine or create a new machine from it.

Once you've installed all required packages, you can take a snapshot or make a backup and use that to restore your machine to a state without your application on it.

See for instance [Digital Ocean's Snapshot and Backups](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/digitalocean-backups-and-snapshots-explained)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive asnwer! I understand. But setting up a complete system with all necessary components (in my case mono, database etc.) always takes a lot of work.Is it possible to make a snappshot of installed components so that recreating of a system is easier. (Be kind with me but as coming from Windows setting up a Linux systems still is a challenge for me)

Comment: @Thomas. I've amended my answer for that.